# Call a function outside of ViewModel scope

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

I have the following code outside the scope of my view model and i am attempting to call it with a click binding.

```
function Policy(data) {
    var self = this;
    Object.keys(data).forEach(function(prop) {
        self[prop] = data[prop];
    });

    var generate = function() {
        console.log("test");
        // window.open("www.google.com")
        // window.open("{{ url_for('genreport') }}/" + qvm.letter() + '/' + self.id);
    }

}
```

however, when i try to call the function i get that generate is not defined. the code for my binding is below

```
<button class="btn btn-lg btn-primary btn-block" data-bind="click: function(){ generate() }">Generate</button>
```

I have tried calling Policy.generate, $data.generate, and i cannot get this function to call.

I know this issue is simple and im probably missing something that should be smashing me in the face but i'm oblivious, any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

The fix was just to place the said function within the scope of my ViewModel, it is now fixed.

Answer (score 0):

You have declared `generate` using a local variable. It is not visible outside the scope of `Policy`. If you want to create `Policy.generate`, you should do that:

```
Policy.generate = function () {
```

Comment: I was just about to update the question saying i had fixed it by moving it within the scope of the view model not sure why i placed it outside to begin with, thank you for your comment.